# Why does my USB port make a beep when connected to my cell phone?

Tags: usb, audio, desktop-computer

I have various Android devices when I connect my devices to my PC, why USB port makes **beep** even I am listing songs **beep** keeps coming from headphones. Specially when I transfer some data beep makes itself strong until data copied to the device Vice versa. I am using Windows 8.1 64bit.

Comment: Yes you are right I am using front usb ports.

Comment: I have posted an answer detailing the cause and some possible solutions. This being said, I feel that the problem isn't all that uncommon and that there might be better answers somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the USB ports and the audio channels are close together (since the PC tower at that point is cramped). From personal experience, most home computers tend not to shield the audio and USB cables that connect to a main HUB that clumps everything in the front panel of the computer.

Also, inside the PC, the audio channel tends to be sensitive to outside interference. As an USB connexion is digital, if there isn't sufficient separation from the cables at any point, some of the power on the USB cable can leak to the audio one, and that leakage can be perceived as a faint set of beeps or electronic noise, depending on other electronic instruments nearby (I also have a HDD nearby, so I can also hear it). You can hear it most whenever you are transferring files to and from the device, as most times the device is idle.

Despite not having tried it, one possible solution would be to shield the audio cables, using either a fine metal mesh or a piece of aluminum foil, wrapped around them (akin to a Faraday cage). Separating the USB cables and the audio ones may also work, depending on your configuration.

Comment: For future reference, you should wait a while before accepting an answer: this way, people can still try to give better answers to your problem.

Comment: But your answer was correct I used my back usb ports and noise was gone.